# Range of Trigonometric function

Tags: calculus

> Range of $f(x)=\cos^{8}x+\sin^{14}x\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ For upper bond::

Using $\sin^{14} x \leq \sin^2x$ and $\cos^{8}x\leq \cos^2 x$

So we get $$\sin^{14}x+\cos^8 x\leq \sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$$

So $\max$ of function $f(x)=1$

Now for lower bond::

$\sin^{14}x+\cos^8 x>0\;,$ Bcz $\sin^{14}x$ and $\cos^8 x$ can not $0$ simultaneously

My question is How can we calculate Minimum value of $f(x)\;,$ Help required, Thanks

Comment: I cannot see any elegant solution. Put $s=\sin^2x$. You get a polynomial of degree 7. It has a minimum near $s=0.5861$. To find the minimum you need to solve the degree 6 derivative numerically, then substitute etc. The answer for the min value is $\approx 0.05311$.

Comment: @JustinBenfield How can $f(x)$ be negative for real $x$?

Comment: Your maximum needs some more argument. All you have proved is that the upper bound of $f(x)$ is less than or equal to $1$: not that it equals $1$.

Comment: @MartinKochanski True, but it is obvious that 1 can be realized, eg by taking $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**:

Let $a = \cos^2x, b = \sin^2x\implies a+b = 1\implies f(a,b) = a^4+b^7=a^4+(1-a)^7=g(a), a \in [0,1]\implies g'(a) = 4a^3-7(1-a)^6=0 \implies (\sqrt[3]{4}\cdot a)^3= (\sqrt[3]{7}\cdot (1-a)^2)^3\implies a\sqrt[3]{4}=\sqrt[3]{7}(1-a)^2$. Solving this quadratic equation will give you $2$ critical points in $[0,1]$, and you can use the second derivative test if you like to find out which one is the minima. Then couple with the end points of $0,1$, you can determine the global minimum for $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Considering $$f(x)=\cos^{8}(x)+\sin^{14}(x)$$ the derivetive can simplify to $$f'x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)\left(14 \sin ^{12}(x)-8 \cos ^6(x) \right)$$ If we consider the last term $$14 \sin ^{12}(x)-8 \cos ^6(x) $$ ans define $t=\cos^2(x)$ we then have $$14(1-t)^6=8c^3$$ Rising to power $\frac 13$, this leads to $$\frac{(1-c)^2}{c}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{7}}$$ which is a quadratic in $c$